docker mariab DB master/slave
I setup a docker MariaDB master/slaves replication architecture for my Wordpress website but I noticed no gain for performance and so I am disappointed! But I would like to know what is wrong or what did I miss? Here is the docker-compose file:
services:
  sv-isoluce-db-master-1:
    build:
      context: ./buildimg/mariadb
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: img-isoluce-mariadb
    container_name: ct-isoluce-mariadb-master-1
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-master-1:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./ctconfig/mariadb-master-1.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./ctconfig/01-init-db-master.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-init-db-master.sql
    ports:
      - "3301:3306"
    networks:
      - nw_isoluce_mariadb_cluster_network

  sv-isoluce-db-slave-2:
    image: img-isoluce-mariadb
    container_name: ct-isoluce-mariadb-slave-2
    depends_on:
      - sv-isoluce-db-master-1
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MASTER_HOST=${MASTER_HOST}
      - MASTER_PORT=${MASTER_PORT}
      - REPLICATION_USER=${REPLICATION_USER}
      - REPLICATION_PASSWORD=${REPLICATION_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-slave-2:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./ctconfig/mariadb-slave-2.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    ports:
      - "3302:3306"
    networks:
      - nw_isoluce_mariadb_cluster_network

  sv-isoluce-db-slave-3:
    image: img-isoluce-mariadb
    container_name: ct-isoluce-mariadb-slave-3
    depends_on:
      - sv-isoluce-db-master-1
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MASTER_HOST=${MASTER_HOST}
      - MASTER_PORT=${MASTER_PORT}
      - REPLICATION_USER=${REPLICATION_USER}
      - REPLICATION_PASSWORD=${REPLICATION_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-slave-3:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./ctconfig/mariadb-slave-3.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    ports:
      - "3303:3306"
    networks:
      - nw_isoluce_mariadb_cluster_network

  sv-isoluce-haproxy:
    build:
      context: ./buildimg/haproxy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: img-isoluce-haproxy
    container_name: ct-isoluce-haproxy
    depends_on:
      - sv-isoluce-db-master-1
      - sv-isoluce-db-slave-2
      - sv-isoluce-db-slave-3
    volumes:
      - ./buildimg/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
      - "8888:8888"
    networks:
      - nw_isoluce_mariadb_cluster_network

  sv-isoluce-phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: ct-isoluce-phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - sv-isoluce-db-master-1
      - sv-isoluce-db-slave-2
      - sv-isoluce-db-slave-3
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_HOST: sv-isoluce-db-master-1
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - "3300:80"
    networks:
      - nw_isoluce_mariadb_cluster_network

volumes:
  vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-master-1:
    name: vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-master-1
  vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-slave-2:
    name: vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-slave-2
  vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-slave-3:
    name: vl-isoluce-ct-mariadb-slave-3

networks:
  nw_isoluce_mariadb_cluster_network:
    name: nw_isoluce_mariadb_cluster_network
    driver: bridge

Here is the Dockerfile I used to build the mariadb image (nothing special):
# Image officielle MariaDB comme base
FROM mariadb:latest

# Installation d'utilitaires : iputils-ping...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    iputils-ping \
    vim \
    nano \
    net-tools \
    htop \
    wget \
    curl \
    atop \
    netcat-openbsd \
    systemd \
    procps \
    locate \
    telnet \
    libhiredis-dev \
    libmariadb3 \
    libmariadb-dev

# Expose le port par défaut de MariaDB
EXPOSE 3306

Here is the mariadb configuration file of the master node :
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
gtid_domain_id = 1
server-id = 01
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/master-bin
log-bin-index = /var/log/mysql/master-bin.index
binlog-format = mixed
log_slave_updates = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog = 1
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
general_log = on
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
replicate-do-db = wp_bsarp
log-slave-updates = 1
expire_logs_days = 10
gtid_strict_mode = ON
performance_schema = ON
performance_schema_instrument = '%=ON'
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_current = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_history = ON

and the slaves node configuration file:
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
gtid_domain_id = 1
server-id = 02
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/02-bin
log-bin-index = /var/log/mysql/02-bin.index
binlog_format = mixed
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql/slave-relay-bin.index
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/slave-relay-bin
log_slave_updates = ON
replicate-do-db = wp_bsarp
slave-skip-errors = 1062
skip-slave-start
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
general_log = on
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
gtid_strict_mode = ON
performance_schema = ON
performance_schema_instrument = '%=ON'
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_current = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_history = ON

For the HAProxy ;
global
  log stdout format raw local0 debug
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  stats socket /var/run/api.sock user haproxy group haproxy mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners

defaults
  mode http
  timeout client 30s
  timeout connect 30s
  timeout server 30s
  timeout http-request 30s
  log global

frontend mysql_frontend
  bind *:3307
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  log-format "%ci:%cp [%t] %s %hr %b %tr %ts %ac %fc %bc %rc %sc %sq %bq %hr %hs"
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_len 10 }

  acl is_read_query req.body -m sub "SELECT"
  use_backend mysql_read_backend if is_read_query
  default_backend mysql_write_backend

backend mysql_write_backend
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  option tcp-check
  tcp-check connect
  server hap-mariadb-master-1_write_backend sv-isoluce-db-master-1:3306 check

backend mysql_read_backend
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  option tcp-check
  tcp-check connect
  server hap-mariadb-master-1_read_backend sv-isoluce-db-master-1:3306 check
  server hap-mariadb-slave-2_read_backend sv-isoluce-db-slave-2:3306 check
  server hap-mariadb-slave-3_read_backend sv-isoluce-db-slave-3:3306 check

This works but so slow...any idea ? Thank you
I expect some improvement on performance but actually, it does not change anything, with a unique database server or a distributed master/slave one...
